# Model selection with AIC

Tags: r, information-theory, model-comparison

I have fitted the normal distributions to my claim amount data using the fitdistr in R. How do i fit Multivariate normal distribution (Two dimensional normal distribution) ? I want to choose which one fits my sample data the best using the AIC in R. How do I proceed? I have tried

```
IC<-Mclust(data,G=1) 
IC1<-Mclust(data,G=2)
```

smaller BIC is better model. but how to calculate AIC base on this Mclust result.

Answer (score 2):

The Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) is defined as 2*k - 2*ln(L), where k is the number of parameters in a model and L is the likelihood of the model (maximized for the data by fitting the best parameters).

`Mclust()` returns both of these to you, so you can compute AICs from fields in the returned Mclust objects.

```
require(mclust)
data(iris)
IC <- Mclust(data=iris, G=1)
IC1 <- Mclust(data=iris, G=2)
aic <- 2*IC$df - 2*IC$loglik
aic1 <- 2*IC1$df - 2*IC1$loglik
```

Do `?Mclust` for more information.